# Type of attribute of class for retrieving list from firebase

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: Sample from database]

I have a class Candidat. I want to know what should be the type of attribute « offres » so I can retrieve it from firebase the same way I do for the other attibutes when I build my object this way :

```
Candidat candidat = snapshot.child(mail).getValue(Candidat.class);
```

I have no issues getting the other attributes into my class Candidat with simple casting :

```
private String password;
private String nom;
private String prenom;
private String dateNaissance;
private String sexe;
private String nationalite;
private boolean affichageInfo;
```

But I don't know how to do it with "offres".

Answer (score 0):

It is a `List<Map<String, int>>`. You have an immutable variable type in that map.

Answer (score 0):

Your `offress` looks like an array of numbers, so that should map to:

```
public List<long> offres;
```